# Panels page won't load

Tags: 7, panels

I have created a panels page using Panels and for some reason it takes an age to load. It seemed to have started when I added another panels page as a child of this one, and added a navigation block to the left column.

Is there any way to debug this? I've tried using Firebug to check the Net tab, but it just loads and loads. This is running on my localhost so it must be a code loop somewhere, but I've no idea how to find it.

I've checked the reports.

Drupal 7.8
Panels 7.x-3.0-alpha3
Chaos tools 7.x-1.0-rc1

---

I found this in my log, any ideas?

```
Type    theme
Date    Monday, September 19, 2011 - 12:33
User    admin
Location    http://localhost/project01/admin/structure/pages/nojs/operation/page-about_us/handlers/page_about_us_panel_context_3/content
Referrer    http://localhost/project01/admin/structure/pages/nojs/operation/page-about_us/handlers/page_about_us_panel_context_3/content
Message Theme key "panels_edit_display_form" not found.
Severity    warning
Hostname    127.0.0.1
Operations
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is an issue with the module. Fortunately there is a [patch](http://drupal.org/node/1116522#comment-5029868).